# Sorting Array/ table in lua by time

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I've been researching for quite a while on sorting tables, I see plenty of examples but I can't seem to get them working.

I'm trying to get playerValues from a method and store them into a table (I believe I'm this far) then I want to sort those values by time.

Example code:

What my array looks like

```
sellTest = {}
sellTest.eventType = {}
sellTest.secsSinceEvent = {}
sellTest.buyer = {}
sellTest.seller = {}
sellTest.someParam = {}
sellTest.itemName = {}
sellTest.soldAmount = {}
```

How I'm storing the values

```
for j = 0, totalEvents do
  for i = 0, numEvents do
    sellTest.eventType[i], sellTest.secsSinceEvent[i], sellTest.seller[i],
    sellTest.buyer[i], sellTest.someParam[i], sellTest.itemName[i],
    sellTest.soldAmount[i] = GetPlayerInfo(event(j),SELL_SALES, i )
  end
 end
```

Then How I'm trying to display the table  (Stuck here)

```
local function sortMyTable()
  table.sort(sellTest, function(a, b) return secsSinceEvent[2]  > secsSinceEvent[2] end)

  for k,v in ipairs(sellTest) do
    print(v[1].. ' == '.. v[2])
  end
end
```

I know that table is completely wrong, I'm still learning LUA and researching the table functionality.

Update, Should I store data like this?

Example 1:?

```
local sellTest = {}
    sellTest['eventType'] = {}
    sellTest['secsSinceEvent'] = {}
```

or 
Example 2:

```
local sellHistory = {
  eventType = {},
  secsSinceEvent = {}
}
```

Comment: Was that sort function supposed to be `a.secsSinceEvent[2] > b.secsSinceEvent[2]` or something like that? Because as written it is constant and uses neither of its arguments.

Comment: Also, why are you splitting up your data for a single event into multiple parallel arrays? Why not just have a single array of events each a table of all the relevant data?

Comment: Humm, I've been trying different things? what do you mean single array of events? 

Added what I think you mean to my comment above

Comment: Assuming I understand your code correctly the various bits of information for a sell event are spread out among the sellTest.* tables. With the data for the Nth event being in the Nth indexed field of each table. Instead of that have a single sellHistory table which contains, as its numbered indices, tables of the form `{eventType = ..., secsSinceEvent = ..., buyer = ..., seller = ..., itemName = ..., soldAmount = ...}` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What my array looks like

You mean what my array**s** look like, because you posted 8 of them. You only need one:

```
sellHistory = {}
```

Each element of this array should contain an event info record, which has fields for `eventType`, `secsSinceEvent`, etc.

```
for i = 0, numEvents do
    local e = {}
    e.eventType, e.secsSinceEvent, e.seller, e.buyer, e.someParam, e.itemName, e.soldAmount 
        = GetPlayerInfo(event(j), SELL_SALES, i )
    table.insert(sellHistory, e)
end
```

Now sorting the event info by time is easy:

```
table.sort(sellHistory, function(a,b) return a.secsSinceEvent > b.secsSinceEvent end)
```

Then (for example):

```
for i,event in ipairs(sellHistory) do
  print(event.eventType, event.secsSinceEvent, event.seller)
end
```

---

What you were doing is taking the event info, writing each value into separate arrays which were correlated by index. This makes stuff like sorting very difficult, as you discovered.

---

By the way, I don't know what API you're coding against, but judging only by the name -- `secsSinceEvent` -- your logic is probably broken.

If an event occurs at 1:00:00  and you call `GetPlayerInfo` at 1:00:01, the `secsSinceEvent` will be 1.

If an event occurs at 2:00:00 and you call `GetPlayerInfo` at 2:00:50, the `secsSinceEvent` will be 50.

If you sort by `secsSinceEvent` you'll show the second event as older than the first event, which is not true.

If your purpose is just to maintain a history sortable by event time, you need to use `secsSinceEvent` to calculate the time of the event by subtracting `secsSinceEvent` from the current time and saving that as the timestamp for the event. I'm not sure why the API doesn't simply give you the event time in the first place. Perhaps they want to side step time zone issues.

Comment: Great! this is working! :) I've spent so many hours on this.   I have the list in Descending order, I'll see if I can get it ascending.. EDIT: Yup < was it, thank you so much MUD!